# Any way to have gmaps4rails open the map in Street View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails, google-street-view

I've tried changing the zoom level, but it always stays in the map mode. Couldn't find any info on the wiki either. Any help or other suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Ended up just using Google's Javascript API. It went something like this:

```
pos = new google.maps.LatLng( <%= latitude %>, <%= longitude %> );

var div = document.getElementById('streetViewContainer');
var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(div);
sv.setPosition( pos );
sv.setVisible( true );

// find the heading by looking from the google car pos to the venue pos
var service = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
service.getPanoramaByLocation( pos, 50, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) 
    {   
        carPos = result.location.latLng;
        heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading( carPos, pos );
        sv.setPov( { heading: heading, pitch: 0, zoom: 1 } );
    }
} );
```

Comment: +1 and sorry, the gem doesn't support this right now, your contribution would be welcome!

Comment: To be clear the element id is actually the id of the map element. Also if you want a close button: `google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(div, { enableCloseButton: true });`

Comment: Thanks. BTW, does the gmaps4rails gem now support StreetView?