# How to display two gmaps4rails on same page one regular map and one in street view (Google Maps and Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I am using gmaps4rails and have one map going already when someone clicks on a marker a modal pops up. In the modal I want a map in street view instead of the picture.

So far this is what I have in my index.html.erb I am just confused on how to do this. I know there are resources on the gmaps4rails wiki but I do not know where to even place the resources on my page. Someone with some insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
<% provide(:page_title, 'Browse Coverage') %>

<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=blablablaM&libraries=places"></script>

<% content_for :scripts %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'creative/marker_cluster.js', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'creative/infobox_packed.js', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 900px;'></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!--Basic Table-->
                    <div class="panel panel-green margin-bottom-40">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                            <div class = "name"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="thumbnail-img">
                                    <div class="overflow-hidden streetViewContainer">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <button class="btn-u btn-u-lg rounded-4x btn-u-green" type="button"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Check Availability</button>
                            <button class="btn-u btn-u-lg rounded-4x btn-u-green" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add to Favorites</button>

    <%= form_tag(controller: "maps", action: "favorite", method: "post")%>
      <%= submit_tag "Favorite"%>

                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table paneltb">


                        </table>

                    </div>
                    <!--End Basic Table-->
  </div>
</div>


  <script type = "text/javascript">
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google', {
               markers:
                      {clusterer: {
                        gridSize: 60,
                        maxZoom: 20,
                        styles: [ {
                          textSize: 10,
                          textColor: '#ff0000',
                          url: 'assets/creative/m1.png',
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60 }
                        , {
                          textSize: 14, 
                          textColor: '#ffff00',
                          url:'assets/creative/m2.png',
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60 }
                        , {
                         textSize: 18, 
                         textColor: '#0000ff',
                         url: 'assets/creative/m3.png',
                         width: 60,
                         height: 60}
                        ]}}
            });
var current;
function initialize(){
  handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'map'} }, function() {

    markers_json = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;
    markers = _.map(markers_json, function(marker_json){
      marker = handler.addMarker(marker_json);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
      _.extend(marker, marker_json);
      return marker;
    });

    getLocation();



    markers.map(function(elem, index) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(elem.getServiceObject(), "click", function(evt) {
        var id = elem.id,
            number = elem.number,
            name = elem.name,
            zipcode = elem.zipcode,
            latitude = elem.latitude,
            longitude = elem.longitude

         $(".name").html("<h3 class='panel-title'><i class='fa fa-id-card'></i>"+number+"</h3>")
         $(".paneltb").html("<thead><tr><th>Panel</th><th>Location</th><th>Zip Code</th><th>Latitude</th><th>Longitude</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>"+number+"</td><td>"+ name + "</td><td>"+zipcode+"</td><td>"+latitude+"</td><td>"+longitude+"</td></tr></tbody>")


        $('#myModal').modal('show')
            current = elem;
        });




    })
  });
    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.


}
function getLocation(){
  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayOnMap);
  }
  else{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayOnMapError);
  }
};
function displayOnMap(position){

  marker2 = handler.addMarker({
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude,
    picture: {
        url: "<%= asset_path 'creative/1499326997_Untitled-2-01.png' %>",
        width:  48,
        height: 48
        },
    infowindow:  "You are Here!"
  });
  handler.map.centerOn(marker2);
  handler.getMap().setZoom(10);
};

function displayOnMapError(position){

  marker2 = handler.addMarker({
    lat: 34.0522,
    lng: -118.2437,
    picture: {
        url: "<%= asset_path 'creative/1499326997_Untitled-2-01.png' %>",
        width:  48,
        height: 48
        }
  });
  handler.map.centerOn(marker2);
  handler.getMap().setZoom(10);
};




initialize();


</script>

<script type = "text/javascript">



pos = new google.maps.LatLng( <%= latitude %>, <%= longitude %> );


var div = document.getElementById('streetViewContainer');
var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(div);
sv.setPosition( pos );
sv.setVisible( true );

// find the heading by looking from the google car pos to the venue pos
var service = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
service.getPanoramaByLocation( pos, 50, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) 
    {   
        carPos = result.location.latLng;
        heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading( carPos, pos );
        sv.setPov( { heading: heading, pitch: 0, zoom: 1 } );
    }
} );

</script>
```

Here is an example of what the map looks like and when it opens a modal pops up the grey area is where I want to put another map.

[image: gmaps4rails]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out as I said I am using gmaps4rails and I have done some customizing instead of an infobox I have a modal, marker clusters, and now a map within the modal for google street view. I just added the code that was written for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10938316/7039895 and wrote it in the part where I customized my modal passing the values longitude and latitude into the code. Worked perfectly.

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google', {
               markers:
                      {clusterer: {
                        gridSize: 60,
                        maxZoom: 20,
                        styles: [ {
                          textSize: 10,
                          textColor: '#ff0000',
                          url: 'assets/creative/m1.png',
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60 }
                        , {
                          textSize: 14, 
                          textColor: '#ffff00',
                          url:'assets/creative/m2.png',
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60 }
                        , {
                         textSize: 18, 
                         textColor: '#0000ff',
                         url: 'assets/creative/m3.png',
                         width: 60,
                         height: 60}
                        ]}}
            });
var handler2 = Gmaps.build('Google');
var current;
function initialize(){
  handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'map'} }, function() {

    markers_json = <%=raw @hash.to_json %>;
    markers = _.map(markers_json, function(marker_json){
      marker = handler.addMarker(marker_json);
      handler.fitMapToBounds();
      _.extend(marker, marker_json);
      return marker;
    });

    getLocation();



    markers.map(function(elem, index) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(elem.getServiceObject(), "click", function(evt) {
        var id = elem.id,
            number = elem.number,
            name = elem.name,
            zipcode = elem.zipcode,
            latitude = elem.latitude,
            longitude = elem.longitude



         $(".name").html("<h3 class='panel-title'><i class='fa fa-id-card'></i>"+number+"</h3>")
         $(".paneltb").html("<thead><tr><th>Panel</th><th>Location</th><th>Zip Code</th><th>Latitude</th><th>Longitude</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>"+number+"</td><td>"+ name + "</td><td>"+zipcode+"</td><td>"+latitude+"</td><td>"+longitude+"</td></tr></tbody>")

         pos = new google.maps.LatLng( latitude, longitude );

        var div = document.getElementById('map2');
        var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(div);
        sv.setPosition( pos );
        sv.setVisible( true );

        // find the heading by looking from the google car pos to the venue pos
        var service = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
        service.getPanoramaByLocation( pos, 50, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) 
            {   
                carPos = result.location.latLng;
                heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading( carPos, pos );
                sv.setPov( { heading: heading, pitch: 0, zoom: 1 } );
            }
        })

        $('#myModal').modal('show')
            current = elem;
        });










    })
  });
    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.


}
function getLocation(){
  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayOnMap);
  }
  else{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayOnMapError);
  }
};
function displayOnMap(position){

  marker2 = handler.addMarker({
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude,
    picture: {
        url: "<%= asset_path 'creative/1499326997_Untitled-2-01.png' %>",
        width:  48,
        height: 48
        },
    infowindow:  "You are Here!"
  });
  handler.map.centerOn(marker2);
  handler.getMap().setZoom(10);
};

function displayOnMapError(position){

  marker2 = handler.addMarker({
    lat: 34.0522,
    lng: -118.2437,
    picture: {
        url: "<%= asset_path 'creative/1499326997_Untitled-2-01.png' %>",
        width:  48,
        height: 48
        }
  });
  handler.map.centerOn(marker2);
  handler.getMap().setZoom(10);
};




initialize();
```